# animate().alpha weird behavior on Android 3.2

Tags: android, jquery-animate, tablelayout

I'm doing some changes in a recently released app from 4.0 to 3.2.
It works well on 4.0, after reading the SDK diferences with 3.2 and doing some testing I finally get compiled without errors.
I share the same coding in allmost all activities in order to show/hide different layouts, the main screen, a progress indicator screen, results, screen, inside the same activity.
For example this one manage 2 layouts

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                        : View.GONE);
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                        : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);


    }
}
```

with this XML

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<!-- Login progress -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_Iniciando"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Login form -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:hint="@string/txt_Usuario"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:hint="@string/txt_Password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnChange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="btnLogin_OnClick"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_Ingresar" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</merge>
```

This works fine both in 3.2 and 4.0, but the next one

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(int form) { //lista, estado, resultado, null
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        switch (form) {
            case NULL:
                mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mConfigStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case ESTADO:
                mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mConfigStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        switch (form) {
            case NULL:
                mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case ESTADO:
                mConfigStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

with this XML

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".ConfigActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblConfig"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/txt_interfaz"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtConfig"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_address"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editConfig"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="20"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="18sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPair"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnPair_OnClick"
            android:text="@string/txt_pair"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/config_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/config_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_Iniciando"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

just crash the app on 3.2

The LogCat is

```
05-19 17:45:14.685: E/AndroidRuntime(11473): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 17:45:14.685: E/AndroidRuntime(11473):    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animatePropertyBy(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:614)
05-19 17:45:14.685: E/AndroidRuntime(11473):    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animateProperty(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:564)
05-19 17:45:14.685: E/AndroidRuntime(11473):    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.alpha(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:504)
05-19 17:45:14.685: E/AndroidRuntime(11473):    at com.enable.certignv.android.ConfigActivity.showProgress(ConfigActivity.java:132)
```

Almost all the activities throwing this error contains TableLayouts, after replacing the 4.0 GridLayouts for compatibility with 3.2, but I'm not sure how much this is related with my problem.

If I comment the .alpha() end of sentences the code don't chrash but neither it works as should, it means, don't change the visibility of the layout so the first one is always on top and none of the other shows as expected.

After a few days going all around this particular problem I don't have any other ideas for testing.

Did someone experienced something like this? Unfortunately the client have a lot of tablets with Android 3.2, they don't have an official upgrade to ICS and they don't want their tablets be jailbreaked to 4.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just found this Android 3.2 issue:

[Issue 18803: ViewPropertyAnimator crashes if called early](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18803)